# JQuery Ajax Post :500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to perform this AJAX post but for some reason I am getting a server 500 error.

```
   $.ajax({
            url: '.../PublicAPI.svc/Register',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: '{ "ApiKey": "'+$('#ApiKey').val()+'", "LanguageId": "'+$('#LanguageId').val()+'", "Password": "'+$('#Password').val()+'","Username": "'+$('#Email').val()+'" }',
    success: function( response, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Can any body help me to find out what is the issue?

Comment: If you get a 500 internal error it is a server side error or your ajax call is not executed on the good url.

Answer (score 2):

You are using three dots in your AJAX URL. Try using 2 dots, and the server error should go away.

```
url: '../PublicAPI.svc/Register',
```

See [Three or more dots followed by a slash in url causes an internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210994/three-or-more-dots-followed-by-a-slash-in-url-causes-an-internal-server-error)

Comment: Hi Jan,
"..." is just an example, actually I have complete URL, "http://abc.com/PublicAPI.svc/Register".

dot is not the issue.

Comment: Then in that case I refer you to the comment from phemios. You problem is server side and nothing you have provided can help us diagnose that issue. Can you provide any errors from server logs? Is it definately a 500? If your request to a different sub-domain or domain then your CORS setup must be correct. If it is a CORS problem then I will provide more detail on how to work around the issue.